# SQL - selectively put items into array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to selectively choose what to put inside an array using `ARRAY_AGG` in BQ? I have the following table where I'm trying to put deferred cases into an array nested under the respective final case.

```
case_id  status    date       primary_date primary_case_id primary_status
abc123   deferred  2022-05-01 2022-08-01   ghi789          final
def456   deferred  2022-07-01 2022-08-01   ghi789          final
ghi789   final     2022-08-01 2022-08-01   ghi789          final
jkl123   deferred  2022-10-01 2022-12-01   mno456          final
mno456   final     2022-12-01 2022-12-01   mno456          final
```

But I get something like this when using `ARRAY_AGG` where the final case is also included in the array.

```
primary_date primary_case_id primary_status deferred_cases 
2022-08-01   ghi789          final          case_id  status    date
                                            ghi789   final     2022-08-01
                                            def456   deferred  2022-07-01
                                            abc123   deferred  2022-05-01
2022-12-01   mno456          final          case_id  status    date
                                            mno456   final     2022-12-01
                                            jkl123   deferred  2022-10-01
```

Is there a way to remove the final cases from the array to get the result below?

```
primary_date primary_case_id primary_status deferred_cases 
2022-08-01   ghi789          final          case_id  status    date
                                            def456   deferred  2022-07-01
                                            abc123   deferred  2022-05-01
2022-12-01   mno456          final          case_id  status    date
                                            jkl123   deferred  2022-10-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * replace(
  array(select as struct * 
    from t.deferred_cases
    where date != primary_date
    order by date desc
  ) as deferred_cases)
from (
  select primary_case_id,
    array_agg(struct(primary_date, primary_status) order by date desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*, 
    array_agg(struct(case_id, status, date)) deferred_cases
  from your_table
  group by primary_case_id
) t
```

[image]

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you Mikhail! I was wondering what does this line do? `array_agg(struct(primary_date, primary_status) order by date desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*`

Comment: sure. it takes all entries and "survives" only the last/latest one based on date - but this is still an array with one element so you need to extract that element using `offset(0)`. but because this extracted element is a struct - you use `*` to "flatten" that struct into separate columns. hope this helps! confirm if so :o)

Comment: That makes sense ty! I think I was confused because I actually had a cte that extracted the primary values: `cte as (select *,
first_value(date) over (order by date desc) as primary_date,
first_value(case_id) over (order by date desc) as primary_case_id,
first_value(status) over (order by date desc) as primary_status
from earlier_cte)`

Comment: Does the `select as struct *` in the outer query just flatten the struct in order to compare the date values to the `primary_date`?

Comment: just remove `as struct` and see result :o)

Comment: Oh I see from the error message that the array needs the struct to be built. Hmm I guess it's still not clear to me the mechanism behind how the dates from the array are being compared to values outside of the array.

Comment: it is not about array, rather about specific row. all values in the row available! and can be used